# need to speed up file transfer between laptop and network hard drive

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, file-transfer

I have a very basic wifi router, I've received it from my ISP.

I have External network hard drive "Seagate Central 3T"

Network hard is connected to the router via Ethernet cable.

When I send files from my laptop, **via wifi** connection, the speed be ~ 1.25 MB/S

**using Ethernet cable is not an option, since it's hard to me to add cables around the home.**

I need to make file transfer speed to be faster .. I transfer files to usb HDD with speed not less than  37 MB/S.

is there any router can achieve this speed? or it is something else!?

Comment: Oh, "via wifi". That makes it easy to answer: Use wired.

Comment: Oh, brilliant..

Answer (score 1):

You are using WiFi, and WiFi have different limits depending on what your router and wifi card are capable of.

*The following will take in mind that you will use consumer-grade hardware in a house environment where conditions are optimal (not much interference from signal degration through objects)*

2.4Ghz band is limited to about 40mbps in optimal conditions, where 5Ghz can reach 120mbps if all devices support 802.11ac (unlikely). If you can use 5Ghz band it is preferable, but it would be faster to connect the laptop through cable to the router temprarily so you will reach a speed of 100mbps or 1000mbps depending on what is supported on the router and modem and the cable that is used.

EDIT: it seems from other reactions and comments that you need it to be wifi, not using a cable. You may want to edit your post to include that information...

Anyway, your laptop supports the 5Ghz band: 802.11a which will get you a faster speed, but your modem/router does not. Adding an accesspoint (AP for short) that supports the 5ghz band will improve your overall wifi speeds, but keep in mind, that one of the downsides of using the 5Ghz band is, that because the frequency is so much higher, the signal degrades much easier, meaning you won't be able to get a good reception if the AP is in one room, and you are in the other.

So get an AP and place it closest to the position you are going to sit most of your time. If there are 2 locations and they are in separate rooms, get 2 AP's. If you sit on multiple locations in one room, see if there's a spot near the wall that has free range to all these locations, and place the AP there. You will need to bring a LAN cable to the AP though, and power as well, but once they're in place, they don't need to move.

It still won't be as fast as using a LAN cable, but it will be faster than what you have now. If the increase in speed is really worth spending so much money on, I don't know. Depends on how much money you are willing to make it a bit more speedy.

Comment: my router is "huawei HG530" my laptop is "lenovo z510" .. what do you think?

Comment: Using a LAN cable is the way to go here.

Comment: Your solution - use ethernet - is correct, but your stuff about WIFI speeds is incorrect - 2.4 ghz with 802.11n can theoretically push 600mbps (but not practically, and only with matched hardware). 802.11ac only operates on 5 gig band, not 2.4 gigs, and is theoretically capable of about 7gbits in ideal conditions with expensive/theoretical gear - Not all devices need to be ac to get high speed on it either.

Comment: @davidgo theoretically it should, but my experience with consumer hardware is that the actual speeds you get with speedtests is far lower. I have a D-Link DIR 868-L which is currently the fastest consumer WiFi solution available and a speedtest gives me 120/12 mbit per second. So yeah, in theory the values are different, agreed, practically especially concerning consumer hardware that is most likely present for every SuperUser user out there, these measurements are what matters. But I'll edit my post to clarify that.

Comment: @AhmedMetwally based on your comments on the other answer, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @LPChip .. I've edited my question based on your advice. And I like your new answer.. I consider it as one of my options ... acording to money .. I don't know the prices .. but If there something that will give me a real change in speed and the price around $100 I'll buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Look like Huawei HG530 have one antenna 802.11n radio with 40 MHz band support. So it limited to rate 150 Mbit/s =~ 14 MB/s in ideal conditions.

In noisy environment with many other AP 1,2 MB/s look real.

Look like z510 use [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-N 7260](http://ark.intel.com/products/75440/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-N-7260) which support MIMO 2x2

Switching to MIMO 2x2 router (or AP) must double your speed, if wireless is your bottleneck now.

Use Ethernet is best advice.

But try use other wireless channel.

ADD

At router:

- Don't use TKIP encryption if possible, it limit speed. Use AES or both compatible mode if possible.
- Use n only mode, if possible
- Try use RTS/CTS by lovering treshold to 0 or 300. It lover performance in general, but allov better cooperation with old bg wireless and can actually rise performance.

Comment: Look like we have a solution here .. do you recommend any MIMO 2x2 or AP router (with good price) ? .... and for using Ethernet cable, sometimes I forced to use it .. but .. it's not the ideal solution for me .. this setup is in my home, it is hard to put Ethernet cable in everywhere around the home.

Comment: This router does support 802.11n which is MIMO 2x2. So no need to invest in a new device here.

Comment: Possibly. Huawei make routers with same name but different hardware. All found photos show only one antenna. http://i4.otzovik.com/2012/09/28/274848/img/89646168_b.jpg Open Your device and check.

Comment: Really performance too low even if no MIMO used. it because noisy environment or bad (partially broken) wireless.